# Colliders in unity behaving the way they, as I think, shouldn't

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am learning to work with unity now and I noticed one error. I am working with 2D and have two box colliders.

One of them is:

```
Size  : X = 8, Y = 0.3  
Center: X = 0, Y = 4.9
```

The Other one is

```
Size  : X = 3, Y = 0.6  
Center: X = 0, Y = 3.95
```

So from this information we can see that the gap between those two colliders is 0.5, but a rigidbody with a circle collider with a radius of 0.25 is not able to move through that gap, it gets stuck.

Maybe there's something I don't know about the way colliders work and you could shed some light.

Comment: the gap is 8-3=5 and 0.3-0.6=-0.3 ...

Comment: Well, the center of the first collider is at y axis of 4.9 and the size of it is 0.3, which means the bottom of the collider is at 4.75 (4.9 - 0.3/2). Then again the center of the second collider is at 3.95 and the size is 0.6 which means the top of the second one is at 4.25 (3.95 + 0.6/2). So the gap between the bottom of the first and the top of the second collider is 0.5 (4.75 - 4.25). And if the radius of the circle collider is 0.25 it should fit in perfectly in that gap. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: both objects are at the same position? There's one more thing to consider: collision shapes are not precise, a tiny threshold around each shape exists where bodies are moved to after collision resolve, ie their shapes never touch exactly at the same location

Comment: They are not at the same position is it really that hard to see. X axis is at the same position, Y axis is different, therefore they are NOT at the same position. Thanks for the explanation of the shape of colliders though. :)